# How to create nexus 6 emulator in android studio

Tags: android-studio, emulation

I have installed the latest release of android studio(Android Studio 1.0 RC 1). I have also updated the latest SDK. I am trying to create a nexus 6 emulator in android studio. After I click finish in the wizard nothing is happening. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to create a Virtual Device

- Open the **AVD Manager**
- Select **Create Virtual Device**
- In the **Phone** category select **Nexus 6** and click Next
- Select a **System Image** and click Next
- Change the **AVD Name** to something that you will
  recognise, change any other options and click Finish

#### How to launch a virtual device

- Select the name of the device you have just created in the AVD
  Manager
- Click on the little **green play arrow** to launch

Comment: I use eclipse Adt. There is no Nexus 6 in list of devices